# Access other post fields to create a complex validation condition

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm sending request data with parent/child relationships (1 level max depth). So `parent_id` references itself in the table as a fk.

`debug($this->request->getData())` yields:

```
[
    "activities": [
        [
            "name": "Parent Activity",
            "id": 3,
            "parent_id": null,
            "quantity": null,
        ],

        [
            "name": "Child Activity",
            "id": 4,
            "parent_id": 3,
            "quantity" :5
        ],

        [
            "name": "Parent Activity 2",
            "id": 7,
            "parent_id": null,
            "quantity": null,
        ],

    ]
]
```

I want to create a Validation rule that will force parent activities who have no children ( nodes with parent_id pointing to them ) to have `quantity"` filled in (this can be any arbitrary field, I have a few others).

The most straight forward way I can think is by looping/manipulating the request data and marking it, but is there a nice Cake way of doing this and possibly in the Validation?

```
$data = $this->request->getData();
$collection = new \Cake\Collection\Collection($data);
```

// filter/map so I can create a new key to count the # of children, thus manipulating the data as such:

```
[
    "activities": [
        [
            "name": "Parent Activity",
            "id": 3,
            "parent_id": null,
            "quantity": null,
            "children": 1
        ],

        [
            "name": "Child Activity",
            "id": 4,
            "parent_id": 3,
            "quantity" :5
        ],

        [
            "name": "Parent Activity 2",
            "id": 7,
            "parent_id": null,
            "quantity": null,
            "children": 0
        ],

    ]
]
```

Then I could use the **children** as a condition in Validation rather than something more complicated. Though manipulating the request data doesn't seem that clean. Open to any other suggestions.

Using Cake3.

Answer (score 1):

Use [conditional validation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#conditional-validation).

Example taken from the link above:

```
$validator->add('picture', 'file', [
    'rule' => ['mimeType', ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']],
    'on' => function ($context) {
        return !empty($context['data']['show_profile_picture']);
    }
]);
```

$context is the data, just add your logic to check $context in the closure.

Comment: What if I have a notEmpty condition? `$context` only provides the data for that field, no? Is there a way I can access the other fields from there if I don't do that child_count manipulation?

Comment: Well, did you try to debug($context)? It's all there.